# Stack in Exception for lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

When I get exception, it's quite hard to read error stack if I have lambda functions.

For example for this code:

```
public void Test()
{
    Func<AnotherClass, bool> myLambda = (AnotherClass p) =>
    {
        if (p != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception in method");
        }
        return true;
    };
    AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();
    var r = myLambda(ac);
}

public class AnotherClass
{
}
```

I will get stack error like:

```
"CSharpTests.exe Error: 0 : System.Exception: Exception in method
   at CSharpTests.MarketingEntityManager.<>c.<Test>b__0_0(AnotherClass p)
   at CSharpTests.MarketingEntityManager.Test()
   at CSharpTests.DisplayClassTest.Test()"
```

It was asked many times, what is ***<>c.b__0_0***

But additionally interesting, may be why **myLabda** name I used in my code, was not used for generated name, and b__0_0 was generated.

and where is DisplayName text?

Comment: What do you mean: "It was asked many times," ?

Comment: `myLambda` is just a usual name of a variable, in your case its the name of a reference to a method. However the stack-trace will contain the **methods** name, not the name of the **reference** to that method.

Comment: asked many times in StackOverflow and in internet, but never really explained, as it is as generated code generate names, problem I have to read stack exception, and generated names is NOT really user friendly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your anonymous method **isn't** named `myLambda`. A delegate to the anonymous method is assigned to the `myLambda` local variable. In truth, your anonymous method has a "secret" name, given to it by the compiler, and it is `<Test>b__0_0` (and it is then "hidden" in a nested class named `<>c`), but this name can change between compilations based on the number of other anonymous methods in the same class.

To give a (degenerate) example (that is very common in Javascript), this is legal:

```
((Func<AnotherClass, bool>)((AnotherClass p) =>
{
    if (p != null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception in method");
    }
    return true;
}))(new AnotherClass());
```

Here we don't assign the delegate of the method to any variable, but we use it immediately to invoke the class. The number of brackets is terrible :-)

Another classical example:

```
var coll = new int[5];
var enu = coll.Select(x => x + 1).ToArray();
```

Here `x => x + 1` is an anonymous method (of which a delegate is created by the .NET and passed to `Enumerable.Select`)... There is no name anywhere.

Comment: `c` is probably for class, but do you know the (secret) meaning of `b` and the two numbers? I suppose the last `0` is a counter, but then why the `0` before that?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Looking at sharplab (can't share link, too much long) it seems that the first number is method "number" (the first method in a class is 0, then 1, ...), the second number is anonymous function number. If the anonymous method captures some variables, then it is moved to a `<>c__DisplayClass1_0` subclass, and the numbering changes to `<Test>b__0()`

Comment: Good explanation, I assume I need some [DebuggerAttribute] for lambda functions to show name I want to show. I will post it to user voice.

Comment: @justromagod Now there are even local methods... They get the name mangled like `<classname>g__methodname|0_0`

Answer (score 0):

`myLamda` is just the name of the **delegate** that *references* your method. It´s not the name of that **method**. The latter is generated from the compiler, you can´t change it.

To clearify this a little imagine you didn´t have an anonymous method at all and would reference *named* method with your delegate:

```
myLambda = MyMethod;
```

Now it´s pretty clear that the stacktrace would contain `MyMethod`, not `myLambda`, wouldn´t it?